# Play framework scala Intellij IDE action not found

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I'm trying to setup basic play scala application with Intellij IDE (v 10.5.1).

I followed the instructions http://www.jamesward.com/2011/07/28/setup-play-framework-with-scala-in-intellij

When I start the application from the IDE everything is OK:
01:44:20,734 INFO  ~ Application 'hello6' is now started !

But when I try to open a page in browser I'm getting the error in the output:

application.index action not found

*Action not found
Action application.index could not be found. Error raised is Controller controllers.application not found*

```
play.exceptions.ActionNotFoundException: Action application.index not found
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.getActionMethod(ActionInvoker.java:585)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.resolve(ActionInvoker.java:84)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Controller controllers.application not found
```

Looks like scala compilation just not happening for some reason. Everything works good if I'm running the application directly from play server.

Play v1.2.2, scala-module 0.9.1. Tried in Ubuntu 10.4 and Windows 7.

## Updated adding routes file and Application.scala

```
# Home page
GET     /                                       Application.index

# Ignore favicon requests
GET     /favicon.ico                            404

# Map static resources from the /app/public folder to the /public path
GET     /public/                                staticDir:public

# Catch all
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

============================================================================

```
package controllers

import play._
import play.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {

    import views.Application._

    def index = {
        html.index("Your Scala application is ready!")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This part:

application.index

Seems wrong, shouldn't it be Application.index? With capital A. Check you routes file, maybe it has that typo.

Comment: Yes, routes/urls are case sensitive.

Comment: My routes have Application.index. This is just default project build with play without any modification. It works on play server **play run hello6**.

Comment: @serg can you post the code of routes file and Application.java?

Comment: @Pere Villega added routes and Controllers.scala since I'm using scala module

Comment: @serg sorry wasn't able to answer as I wasn't in front of computers recently... :(

Answer (score 3):

Found solution. In project structure 
**PlayFramework Dependecies** and **Project Libraries** were not configured properly. After I fixed paths to ...play/framework/lib and ...play/modules/scala-0.9.1/lib scala compilation start working.

Answer (score 0):

In the routes, put the action to be

```
controllers.Application.index
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. After going to SBT projects and refresh it went away.

[image: screen shot of SBT projects]